# dequeue function of a list in haskell

Tags: haskell, queue

So I have the following code:

```
module Queue where

class Queue t 
  where
    enqueue :: t a -> a -> t a
    dequeue :: t a -> Maybe (t a, a)
```

--and:

```
module DataQueue where

import Queue
data DQueue a = Empty | Enqueue a (DQueue a)
    deriving (Eq, Show, Read)

instance Queue DQueue
  where
    enqueue (Empty) s = Enqueue s (Empty)
    enqueue (Enqueue v ss) s = Enqueue s (Enqueue v ss)

    dequeue Empty = Nothing
    dequeue (Enqueue a (ss)) = Just(ss)
```

I add an element to a list (enqueue), which works fine. Also I remove an element of the list with the dequeue function. Somehow I get an error for the last line of my dequeue function. It says:

> "Couldn't match expected type `(DQueue a, a)` with actual type `DQueue a`"

I really don't understand how to solve this problem.

Comment: Typically, we think of dequeueing as taking from the front, expressed by a type signature like `dequeue :: t a -> Maybe (a, t a)`. Unrelated: multi-parameter type classes and functional dependencies offer a somewhat nicer expression. `class Queue el q | q -> el where { enqueue :: q -> el -> q; dequeue :: q -> Maybe (el, q) }`. This allows monomorphic (e.g., unboxed) queues to instantiate the class.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the type signature for dequeue:

```
dequeue :: t a -> Maybe (t a, a)
```

...and compare it to what you actually return in that line:

```
dequeue (Enqueue a (ss)) = Just(ss)
```

The types don't match. Can you fix it now?

---

**Walkthrough**

The type of `dequeue` is `t a -> Maybe (t a, a)`, which means it takes one argument of type `t a` and should return a value of type `Maybe (t a, a)`.

Breaking that type down, we start at the outermost 'thing': `Maybe` (the 'thing' is known as a type constructor). So whatever we return must be either `Nothing` or `Just <some value>`.
What goes into the `Just` is what's "inside the `Maybe`", in this case a value of type `(t a, a)`, which is a tuple (pair) of `t a` and an `a`.

Now look at what your code said:

```
dequeue (Enqueue a (ss)) = Just(ss)
```

The return value `Just(ss)` can be written as `Just ss`. Let's determine the type of that `ss`. Since we define:

```
data DQueue a = Empty | Enqueue a (DQueue a)
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^ <-- ss is of this type
```

The type of `ss` is therefore `DQueue a`. So the type of `Just ss` is: `Maybe (DQueue a)`.

Now, we need to return `Maybe (t a, a)`. In our instance of the `Queue` class, the `t` is `DQueue` so the type to return is more specifically: `Maybe (DQueue a, a)`, but we currently have `Maybe (DQueue a)` (remember `ss` is a `DQueue a`, so `Just ss` is `Maybe (DQueue a)`).

So to fix that, instead of `Just ss`, we should return `Just (some pair)`. The pair depends on how we want `dequeue` to behave. If it's like a stack which pops off the last enqueued result, it can be `Just (ss, a)`. Otherwise, see the other answer which discusses how to implement it.

Comment: I understand it now. But struggle to solve it. What should I useful return next to ss?

Comment: @Vendetta, I added some more explanation about the types. I see the other answer deals with queue implementation

Answer (score 4):

Based on your `Queue` class, your `dequeue` function has to return the queue after having removed the element. It should probably be defined as

```haskell
dequeue Empty = Nothing
dequeue (Enqueue a Empty) = Just (Empty, a)
dequeue (Enqueue a (ss)) = do
  (next, v) <- dequeue ss
  return (Enqueue a next, v)
```

This definition assumes you are queuing things up at the beginning of the list and dequeuing them from the end.

The third `dequeue` match is recursively calling `dequeue` to walk to the end of the list, where it picks up the list value (see the second `dequeue` match), then it builds up the Enqueue list again with all but the last element.

This above example takes advantage of the `Maybe` monad and `do` syntax. It could be expressed as the following, if that makes more sense:

```haskell
dequeue (Enqueue a ss) =
  case dequeue ss of
    Just (next, v) -> Just (Enqueue a next, v)
    Nothing -> Nothing
```

Comment: By doing this I get the following error: expected: Just (Enqueue 1 (Enqueue 2 (Enqueue 3 Empty)),4)
 but got: Just (Enqueue 2 (Enqueue 3 (Enqueue 4 Empty)),1)

Comment: That sounds like a different problem with your unit test setup. Are your expectations correct?

Comment: They seem to be correct. I have the following test cases: `dequeue sample1 ~?= (Just (Enqueue 1 $ Enqueue 2 $ Enqueue 3 Empty,4))`

Comment: `dequeue sample2 ~?= (Just (Enqueue "a" $ Enqueue "b" $ Enqueue "c" Empty,"d"))`

Comment: I updated my answer since I was originally showing the functionality of a stack (push/pop) rather than a queue.

Comment: Ok, but now it return always "Nothing" .

Comment: You must have caught it before a quick edit because missed a line. Try again

Comment: Thank you, it works fine now! Can you shortly explain me, what exactly it is doing now? I would like to understand it. :)

Comment: I've added additional detail and an additional way of writing that last `dequeue` pattern.